# Linear Algebra Question , to prove or to disprove

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to pick out true statements from given below

Let $ A $ be a $n \times n $ square matrix over $\mathbb R$ .Then pick out true statements from below:

$1.$  There exists a real symmetric $n \times n$ square matrix $B$ such that $B^{2}$ = $A $

$2$. If  A is symmetric ,there exists a real symmetric $n \times n$ square matrix $B$ such that $B^{2} =A$

$3.$ If A is symmetric ,there exists a real symmetric $n \times n$ square matrix $B$ such that $B^{3}=A$

For A part If i take B as IDENTITY MATRIX ,a part becomes true as existence of "A" Matrix has been shown ,but i donot know how to approach for problem 2 and 3 .Thanks

Comment: How your part a is solved .How are u taking $B$ as identity

Comment: $I^2=I$, so your approach to part 1 is correct if and only if $A=I$.

Comment: what about $A=-I$ for parts 1. and 2.

Comment: @Siminore but they have said there exists "a" matrix , it can be identity

Comment: @Surb please elaborate the case

Comment: @godonichia take $n=1$ and $A = -1$, finding a **real** $B$ such that $B^2 = -1$ could be hard...

Comment: @godonichia: read my answer, and in particular the last sentence of the first paragraph. You need to check whether the statements are true **for all** matrices $A$, and not for particular examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two statements are false: taking $n=1$, we have that $A$ is actually a real number. But you probably know that not every real number has a real square root. (By your comment at the end of your question, I insist that you have to check whether the given statements are true *for all* matrices, and not only for a particular value of $A$.)

For the third statement, remember that a real symmetric matrix has real eigenvalues and is diagonalizable. Thus, $A$ can be written as $PDP^{-1}$, where $D$ is a diagonal real matrix, and $P$ is a real invertible matrix such that $P^{-1}=P^t$. Let $D'$ be the $n\times n$ matrix whose entries are cube root of the entries of $D$: $D'$ is then a diagonal matrix.

Now note that $(PD'P^{-1})^3 = PD'^3P^{-1} = PDP^{-1}=A$. It remains to check that $PD'P^{-1}$ is a symmetric matrix. The coefficient $a_{ij}$ of this matrix is $\sum_{k=1}^n b_{ik}p_{jk}$, where $b_{ik}$ is the coefficient from the $i$th line and $k$th column of $PD'$, and $p_{jk}$ is the coefficient $(j,k)$ of $P$. Since $b_{ik}=\sum_{l=1}^n p_{il}d_{lk}$ and $d_{lk}$ is non-zero iff $l=k$, we have that $a_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^n p_{ik}d_{kk}p_{jk}$, so that $a_{ij}=a_{ji}$ and $PD'P^{-1}$ is indeed symmetric. Thus, the third statement is true.